# OpaquePointer error when trying to convert to swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to convert my project to swift 3 and I have the following errors left. I have tried to do a couple things but I can't get it right.

Error

> "Cannot convert value of type '(OpaquePointer, OpaquePointer, LinphoneRegistrationState, UnsafePointer) -> ()' to specified type 'LinphoneCoreRegistrationStateChangedCb' (aka '@convention(c) (Optional, Optional, _LinphoneRegistrationState, Optional>) -> ()')

**For this code**

```
var registrationStateChanged: LinphoneCoreRegistrationStateChangedCb = {
    (lc: OpaquePointer, proxyConfig: OpaquePointer, state: LinphoneRegistrationState, message: UnsafePointer<Int8>) in

    switch state{
    case LinphoneRegistrationNone: /**<Initial state for registrations */
        NSLog("LinphoneRegistrationNone")

    case LinphoneRegistrationProgress:
        NSLog("LinphoneRegistrationProgress")

    case LinphoneRegistrationOk:
        NSLog("LinphoneRegistrationOk")

    case LinphoneRegistrationCleared:
        NSLog("LinphoneRegistrationCleared")

    case LinphoneRegistrationFailed:
        NSLog("LinphoneRegistrationFailed")

    default:
        NSLog("Unkown registration state")
    }
}
```

**Error**

> "Cannot convert value of type '(OpaquePointer, OpaquePointer, LinphoneCallState, _) -> ()' to specified type 'LinphoneCoreCallStateChangedCb' (aka '@convention(c) (Optional, Optional, _LinphoneCallState, Optional>) -> ()')"

For the below code

```
for var callStateChanged: LinphoneCoreCallStateChangedCb = {
    (lc: OpaquePointer, call: OpaquePointer, callSate: LinphoneCallState,  message) in

    switch callSate{
    case LinphoneCallIncomingReceived: /**<This is a new incoming call */
        NSLog("callStateChanged: LinphoneCallIncomingReceived")

        if answerCall{
            ms_usleep(3 * 1000 * 1000); // Wait 3 seconds to pickup
            linphone_core_accept_call(lc, call)
        }

    case LinphoneCallStreamsRunning: /**<The media streams are established and running*/
        NSLog("callStateChanged: LinphoneCallStreamsRunning")

    case LinphoneCallError: /**<The call encountered an error*/
        NSLog("callStateChanged: LinphoneCallError")

    default:
        NSLog("Default call state")
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 has changed so many things, and the treatment for nullability of pointers is one thing among them.

[SE-0055 Make unsafe pointer nullability explicit using Optional](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0055-optional-unsafe-pointers.md)

With this change, C-pointers without nullability annotations are imported as Optionals.

In your case, `OpaquePointer` -> `OpaquePointer?`, `UnsafePointer<Int8>` -> `UnsafePointer<Int8>?`.

(There are some other changes around `OpaquePointer`, but in your case they seem to be irrelevant.)

Swift well infers the types of closure arguments (when written as in your code). So, why don't you start with omitting all type annotations in your closure?

This line:

```
(lc: OpaquePointer, proxyConfig: OpaquePointer, state: LinphoneRegistrationState, message: UnsafePointer<Int8>) in
```

to:

```
lc, proxyConfig, state, message in
```

And this:

```
(lc: OpaquePointer, call: OpaquePointer, callSate: LinphoneCallState,  message) in
```

to:

```
lc, call, callSate,  message in
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are suggesting with the change. You said to put the first line as lc, proxyConfig, state, message in but it is already in that order.

Comment: @user1079052, I am not saying to change the order. I'm recommending you to remove `(` `: OpaquePointer` `: OpaquePointer` `: LinphoneRegistrationState` `: UnsafePointer<Int8>)`.